# convert array of objects to mongoose query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of mongoose queries like so

```
var q = [{"_id":'5324b341a3a9d30000ee310c'},{$addToSet:{"Campaigns":'532365acfc07f60000200ae9'}}]
```

and I would like to apply them to a mongoose method like so

```
var q = [{"_id":'5324b341a3a9d30000ee310c'},{$addToSet:{"Campaigns":'532365acfc07f60000200ae9'}}]

Account.update.apply(this, q);
```

How can I do this ? How can I convert an array of mongoose query objects to mongoose parameters?

**I tried the following but it doesnt work.**

```
    var q = [{
        "_id": '5324b341a3a9d30000ee310c'
    }, {
        $addToSet: {
            "Campaigns": '532365acfc07f60000200ae9'
        }
    }]

    Account.update(q).exec(function (e, r) {
        console.log(r)
        console.log('ERROR')
        console.log(e)
        console.log('ERROR')
        cb(e, r);
    });
```

Comment: Why not just pass the two params?

Comment: Because the Im getting the array from the functions arguments parameter.  function(){  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);}

Comment: OK -- I added the answer that shows you how to make `apply` work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is pass in the correct object context via `apply` to the `update` method:

```js
Account.update.apply(Account, q)
    .exec(function(e, r) {
    // your code here ...
});
```

The `this` needs to be the `Model` instance, not the global scope context (or whatever else `this` may have been at the time it was called).

Answer (score 0):

Basically seems to be just the way the prototype of the function seems to be passed in. So if you want to build your arguments dynamically then you need to do something like this:

```js
var q = [
  { "_id": account._id },
  { "$addToSet": { "Campaigns": campaign._id } },
];

Account.update( q[0], q[1], (q[2]) ? q[2] : {}, function(err, num) {
```

Essentially then you are **always** passing in the *query*, *update* and *options* documents as arguments. This uses the ternary condition to put an **empty** `{}` document in as the *options* parameter, where it does not exist in your dynamic entry.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the best way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: The context passed to apply was incorrect. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22437901/95190).

Comment: @WiredPrairie It cannot be incorrect when I have tested it and it works. Perhaps you misread the response.

Comment: The `this` context in the original question I meant. Not your answer. Yours works too.